# many-to-many cascade delete

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have many-to-many for **tag** <-> **software**, when i delete tag i want delete all softwares which are related to that tag BUT not which are related to another tag. The business logic here is the following: **Sofware can not exist without a tag**. There are code with two classes and one test below.

Now it deletes all softwares even if they are related to other tags.

How to handle it?

```
@Entity
public class Tag extends Model {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    public String title;

    public Tag(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tags")
    public List<Software> softwares = new LinkedList<Software>();

}


@Entity
public class Software extends Model {

    public String title;
    public String description;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    public Author author;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Tag> tags = new LinkedList<Tag>();

    public Software(String title, String description, Author author) {
       this.title = title;
       this.description = description;
       this.author = author;
    }


    public Software(String title, String description, Author author, Tag ... tags) {
        this(title, description, author);


        if (!Arrays.asList(tags).contains(null)) {

            // it needed if we wand to delete Tags with cascade - when delete Tag, then delete all Softwares related to it
            for (Tag tag : tags) {
               this.tags.add(tag);
            }

            for (Tag tag : tags) {
                tag.softwares.add(this);
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

there is a test:

```
@Test
public void testDelete() throws InterruptedException {

    Tag tag1 = new Tag("tag1").save();
    Tag tag2 = new Tag("tag2").save();

    Author author1 = new Author("name", "email").save();


    new Software("title1", "description1", author1, tag1).save();

    new Software("title3", "description3", author1, tag1, tag2).save();


    tag1.delete();

    // try to find the software
    assertEquals(1, Software.findAll().size());  // IT FAILS - IT DELETES ALL
}
```

Comment: Your questions seems to be confusing. You are deleting tag and asserting on all softwares?

Comment: i just check then one  (1) sofware should remain, because i it's related to tag2 as well. so when i delete tag1 - sofware with title1 should be deleted but sofware with title3 should not.

Comment: Can you assert before tag1.delete()? and see what result are you getting?

Comment: if put the assert before, then it shows: 
Failure, expected:<1> but was:<2>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers, or logic in your service layer is the best bet to achieve it. If you really want it via model, normalize it, here you have a choice to do in the behavior on delete.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after, that a software record is deleted when there are no longer any references joining it to a tag record, is similar to what's given by the `DELETE_ORPHAN` cascade type, but I don't think that's supported for `@ManyToMany`.

As Alexis notes, you can accomplish this by database triggers, but another approach might be to use [interceptors or events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/events.html).

Comment: yes it is not supported in many-to-many, unfortunately. i tend to think do not rely on cascade (get rid of cascade) but do addition actions onDelete in DAO layer which would handle the relations to be able to be deleted then.  (i try do not deal with triggers or extra-logic id database' side)